# Applying values to tags in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have two dataframes (shown as CSV here) that I'd like to join. The first one is tagged as follows:

```
id, name
1, foo
2, bar
3, bar
4, foo
5, foo
```

And the second is a tag guidebook:

```
name, value
foo, 7
bar, 2
```

What I want is:

```
id, name, value
1, foo, 7
2, bar, 2
3, bar, 2
4, foo, 7
5, foo, 7
```

As you can see, every row gets a value according to what is in the name column.

I'd really like to not use a loop for this, as the real database has a few thousand lines, with tens of columns.

Comment: Use `df1.merge(df2, on = 'name', how = 'left')`

Comment: Thanks! That solved it

Comment: "tags" and "dataframe is tagged with..." aren't pandas terms, these are just dataframes with various columns of various dtypes. Here you just needed a `merge`/`join`. In order to understand pandas terminology to help you phrase questions, please take a very quick skim through the quickstart ["10 minutes to pandas"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html)

Answer (score 0):

As MrSoLoDoLo posted as a comment above, the problem is easily solved using the .merge funciton

```
df1.merge(df2, on='name', how='left')
```

Comment: Tomorrow I can accept my own answer as the solution. Nevertheless, the problem can be considered as solved